# How do you integrate standalone Spring Integration with New Relic?

Tags: spring-integration, newrelic

Has anyone integrated New Relic with a standalone instance of Spring Integration?  I also have Spring Integration kicking off Spring Batch jobs.  I have the New Relic agent reporting on the JVM stats.  I would like to treat the tasks run by the task-scheduler threads and different New Relic transactions.  The phrase "spring integration new relic" is extremely generic when using a search engine.

I found this for Spring Batch : https://gist.github.com/slorber/5082320 but I can't find anything for Spring Integration.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use @trace annotation to monitor these tasks if they are not already being instrumented by the New Relic agent

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/java-agent/custom-instrumentation/java-instrumentation-annotation

Comment: I have gotten that far.  I am having trouble figuring out what classes in Spring Integration I need to instrument.  I am really hoping, since StackOverflow is now spring's message board, that someone from the project will see this and lend a hand.

Comment: @Angus, thank you for pointing it one more time. Yes, we see your question. But I'm not familiar with New Relic, so I just don't know what to answer. From other side we have JMX management support and expose to MBeans these SI components: `MessageChannel`, `MessageHandler` and `MessageSource`. Maybe that can help you somehow to figure out what you can `@trace`. From other side we won't mind of contribution: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT !

Answer (score -1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<extension xmlns="https://newrelic.com/docs/java/xsd/v1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="newrelic-extension extension.xsd" name="extension-example" version="1.0" enabled="true">
    <instrumentation>
        <pointcut transactionStartPoint="true" ignoreTransaction="false">
            <interfaceName>org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler</interfaceName>
            <method>
                <name>handleMessage</name>
            </method>
        </pointcut>
    </instrumentation>
</extension>
```

Comment: please explain your solution